# Is it safe to re-download an iOS app within seconds of deleting it, or could this cause problems with data corruption or stability?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications

One of the recommended methods for fixing a malfunctioning app in iOS is to delete and re-download it.

Does iOS have protections in place to prevent misconfiguration or app corruption when a user re-downloads an app immediately (within 5 seconds) after deleting it? When I see people doing things like this, from what I understand about how apps such as gmail or instagram embed themselves into the iOS ecosystem, I’m curious to understand how the operating system protects the user environment from potential misuse.

For context, I am a product of the 2000s when operating systems didn’t have the idiot-proofing they have today. Timing certain actions incorrectly or doing things in the wrong order (eg. not rebooting after uninstalling a program, not waiting after an update to reboot the system) could lead to system instability.

Do you consider concerns such as the above anachronistic?

Comment: The main purpose of deleting an app is to delete the user settings that accompany it. (Don't forget that all your documents in the app's folder may get deleted, too.)

Answer (score 3):

iOS is really very much unlike Windows or even MacOS, though MacOS is adopting some of the security features of iOS.

Your question really comes down to the iOS security model. One thing to note is that iOS security is embedded at every layer, and indeed there are layers of the operating system that are tightly controlled and isolated, and can not be altered, even by Apple. In addition, apps are cryptographically signed by Apple, so their provenance has been vetted, and they are all sandboxed, meaning the app can only access data specific to the app. As far as the app knows, it's the only app running.

In this case, gmail or instagram are not altering or even becoming embedded with the OS, nor the user data. They are sandboxed from other apps and their own data is all they can access. When you remove the app, you remove that app, with the option to also remove its data.

For fascinating details I refer you to the Apple Platform Security White Paper:

https://support.apple.com/guide/security/app-security-overview-sec35dd877d0/web

Comment: My interpretation from this is that app handling by iOS is so modular and simple that uninstallation is pretty much instantaneous (no messy untangling of settings and files distributed throughout the system). The security model means there is no risk of simultaneous installation-uninstallation conflict causing data corruption. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: I believe that is a side effect of the partitioning of data from the operating system, as part of the security model, yes.  For example, on a server, if you ran apps in a Docker container, removing an app is as simple as deleting the Docker container, and its seems simple, but it is complex and not the primary reason for running in Docker.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has always tried to be as idiot-proof as possible in their operating systems and applications, both MacOS and iOS. Remember, their products are "for the rest of us"; they're intended for users who know little about computer technology.

When you tell iOS to uninstall an app, it removes the app and all the data associated with it from the phone. When you see the app disappear from the home screen, all its data has been destroyed. Reinstalling it starts fresh, as if you'd never had a previous installation, so there's no danger of the old data somehow getting mixed in with the new installation.

This is precisely *why* reinstalling is recommended as a way to clear up problems. Sometimes the problems are because the data has become corrupted, and starting fresh clears it all away.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly safe to redownload an iOS app immediately.

Comment: Thanks very much. If you have technical knowledge/experience, could you elaborate? For example about what happens at the OS-level when an app is deleted or user commences a conflicting installation while deletion of the same app is in progress?

Comment: Each app is installed in a single folder. When you delete the app, you delete the folder. The folder is either there or not there. There’s no in between. The scenarios you indicate do not apply on iOS.